# Why does priority_queue use greater<> for ascending order?

Tags: c++, sorting, stl, priority-queue

Why does priority_queue use greater<> for ascending order?

Since sort() method in c++ STL uses greater<>() as a third parameter to make descending order
it's confusing for me that priority_queue uses greater<> for the opposite order.

Why and How does it work this way?
I don't understand how the same greater structure behaves different depending on where it is used.

```
sort<temp.begin(),temp.end(),greater<>()>; // -> descending order

priority_queue<int,vector<int>,greater<int>>; // -> ascending order
```

Comment: _Side note:_ Priority queues are built upon heaps, which use `std::less` to allow new elements to "sink" down in the heap. This, however, brings the largest element to the top of the heap. In order to get the smallest element to rise to the top of the heap, you have to use `std::greater`.

Comment: Sidenote: priority_queue is not technically "ordered"

Comment: _An educated guess:_ (History experts can correct me!) Long ago, a decision was made that `std::less and` `<` should be the default for all comparitors in the Standard Library. I am no expert, but I believe that is still true today. When `std::priority_queue` was designed, it made sense that the element with the highest priority should be first out of the queue. So, `std::priority_queue` was crafted so that it could use `std::less` to output the "biggest" element. To get the smallest, you have to invert the comparison.

Answer (score 2):

You're thinking incorrectly about the meaning of a priority queue. When you remove an item from a priority queue, you are removing the *highest* priority item. Yes, a priority queue uses an ordering functor, but that ordering functor only says which item has the higher priority.

You should not think of the ordering functor as "sorting"; it simply compares the relative priority of the elements.

> the same greater structure

They don't have "the same greater structure". `sort` is an algorithm; it operates on a sequence of elements. `priority_queue` is a container-adapter; it *is* a sequence of elements. `sort` does a thing once and then it's over. `priority_queue` is *the thing*.